# How to set up LuaSnip in NeoVim w/LSP-Zero?

Tags: neovim, snippets, plugin-luasnip, plugin-nvim-cmp

I'm trying to enable snippets in my auto-completion but they are only working for lua files and nothing else. I ve been messing around with nvim-cmp and luasnip itself and even downloaded friendly snippets but still can't get them to work.

LSP-ZERO/CMP CONFIG:

```lua
local lsp = require('lsp-zero').preset('recommended')

lsp.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
  lsp.default_keymaps({ buffer = bufnr, })
end)

-- (Optional) Configure lua language server for neovim
require('lspconfig').lua_ls.setup(lsp.nvim_lua_ls())
lsp.format_on_save()
lsp.setup()

local status, cmp = pcall(require, "cmp")
if (not status) then return end

cmp.setup({
  snippet = {
    expand = function(args)
      require('luasnip').lsp_expand(args.body)
    end,
  },
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
    ['<C-d>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
    ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
    ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
    ['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping.close(),
    ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({
      behavior = cmp.ConfirmBehavior.Replace,
      select = true
    }),
  }),
  sources = cmp.config.sources({
    { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
    { name = 'buffer' },
  }),


})
```

LUASNIP CONFIG

```lua
require('luasnip').config.set_config({
  region_check_events = 'InsertEnter',
  delete_check_events = 'InsertLeave'
})

require('luasnip.loaders.from_vscode').lazy_load()
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [cmp_luasnip](https://github.com/saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip) as a source to nvim-cmp. You can find a minimal example in [lsp-zero's documentation](https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim/blob/v2.x/doc/md/autocomplete.md#add-an-external-collection-of-snippets).

Side note: format_on_save() doesn't do anything if you don't give it any arguments.